# Multiple input onChange issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import './SizeAndColor.css';
const initialData = {
  sizes: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
  data: [
    {
      rowId: uuidv4(),
      color: 'White',
      sizes: [
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'S', qty: 10 },
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'M', qty: 20 },
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'L', qty: 30 },
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'XL', qty: 40 }
      ]
    },
    {
      rowId: uuidv4(),
      color: 'Gray',
      sizes: [
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'S', qty: 50 },
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'M', qty: 60 },
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'L', qty: 70 },
        { fieldId: uuidv4(), sizeName: 'XL', qty: 80 }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const initialFieldValue = {
  id: 0,
  initialData: initialData
};

export default function SizeAndColor() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialFieldValue);

  const onChange = (e, rowId, fieldId) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const updatedData = state.initialData.data.map(row => {
      if (rowId === row.rowId) {
        row.sizes.map(item => {
          if (fieldId === item.fieldId) {
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
              item[name] = value;
            }
          }
          return item;
        });
      }
      return row;
    });
    setState({ ...state, initialData: { ...initialData, data: updatedData } });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            {state.initialData.sizes.map(size => (
              <td key={uuidv4()}>{size}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {state.initialData.data.map(item => (
            <tr key={uuidv4()}>
              <td>{item.color}</td>
              {item.sizes.map(size => (
                <td key={uuidv4()}>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="qty"
                    value={size.qty}
                    onChange={e => {
                      onChange(e, item.rowId, size.fieldId);
                    }}
                  />
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I start typing on any input field, It work only first key press. Than again have to click the input field. Than again after first key press, can not type anything.
I tried it with different scenario. If my `initialData` object doesn't have nested property, It works fine.
how do i solve this issue, please help me.

Comment: Try to formulate a working example on Code Sandbox.

Comment: Here is working example on Code Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-textinput-4spet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are generating new React keys each render.

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        {state.initialData.sizes.map(size => (
          <td key={uuidv4()}>{size}</td> // <-- here
        ))}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {state.initialData.data.map(item => (
        <tr key={uuidv4()}> // <-- here
          <td>{item.color}</td>
          {item.sizes.map(size => (
            <td key={uuidv4()}> // <-- here
              <input
                type="text"
                name="qty"
                value={size.qty}
                onChange={e => {
                  onChange(e, item.rowId, size.fieldId);
                }}
              />
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

When you generate a new React key each render cycle it tells React that these are new components, so the previous ones are unmounted and a new component is instantiated. This is why the inputs lose focus.

## Solution

Use the ids generated in your data so the React keys are **stable**, i.e. they don't change from render to render.

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        {state.initialData.sizes.map((size, index) => (
          // use index since size array likely doesn't change
          <td key={index}>{size}</td> 
        ))}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {state.initialData.data.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.rowId}> // <-- use row id
          <td>{item.color}</td>
          {item.sizes.map(size => (
            <td key={size.fieldId}> // <-- use field id
              <input
                type="text"
                name="qty"
                value={size.qty}
                onChange={e => {
                  onChange(e, item.rowId, size.fieldId);
                }}
              />
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that you generate random keys for input on each render, so React thinks it's a new unrelated field that doesn't need to be focused, you need to replace `key={uuidv4()}` with `key={item.rowId}` and `key={size.fieldId}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the returns, the setState should do the work.